# How can I update a character pointer in a bst struct without causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I made some updates after Joel suggested them in comments, but am still getting a segmentation fault. My code is basically this:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
  char *key;
  char *value;
  unsigned long hash;
} node;
...
void update_node(node* tree, char *key,char *value) {

    unsigned long h = hash(key);
    if( tree->hash == h)
        tree->value = value;
    if( h < tree->hash && tree->left)
        update_node( tree->left, key, value );
    if( h > tree->hash && tree->right)
        update_node( tree->right, key, value );
    if( tree == NULL)
        return;
}
```

But when I try to update it causes a segmentation fault. I've tried researching, but mostly I saw that struct segmentation fault problems had to do with misuse of pointers. For instance, this works fine:

```
node *n = new_node("key","value");
n->value = "value2";
```

It's just updating values on an actual tree that won't work. Is there a way to do this properly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the definition for `find_node()`? Where are the calls where you actually use `update_node()`?

Comment: oh wow... i meant to put `update_node` there. I copied this from my `find_node` function, which I first tried to simply use (it returns a node).

Comment: i'll update, if it works you should submit an answer :)

Comment: Alright. Also, you should be checking for `NULL` first. If `tree->left` or `tree->right` is null, You will dereferencing `NULL` before even arriving at that branch.

Comment: See my previous comment. Step through the code with an imaginary tree structure and you'll see what I'm talking about. In case you were unaware, doing `foo->bar` where `foo == NULL` will cause a segfault.

Comment: Hmm ok :) I did modify the expression in the `if` to read `(h<tree->hash && tree->left)`

Comment: But I will explicitly check for `NULL`

Comment: Don't update the question with the answer, because now it looks like you're asking "Why does <working code here> not work?". I've reverted that edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the tree is `NULL` at the beginning of the function.

```
void update_node(node* tree, char *key,char *value) {

    if( tree == NULL)
        return;

    unsigned long h = hash(key);
    if( tree->hash == h)
        tree->value = value;
    if( h < tree->hash && tree->left)
        update_node( tree->left, key, value );
    if( h > tree->hash && tree->right)
        update_node( tree->right, key, value );
}
```

Not doing this check **before** trying to access its members may cause segfaults.

**EDIT :**

When you create your node to be added to the tree, make sure that you zero all the values. If you don't zero the whole node, it'll contain garbage values.

Therefore, checks like these ...

```
if (tree -> left)
```

Will return `true` even if it shouldn't, because it contains a non-zero garbage value.

Try using `memset(&m, 0, sizeof(myNode));` when creating a node.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing after reading @Joel's comments! But, I tried that already... :(

Also, I did `node* n =NULL; n->left;` and didn't get any segmentation fault or anything...

Comment: I do use `struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` in the node creation function. I try to modify the node value directly, but maybe the easiest way is to delete it and reinsert it? I have delete/insert functions working...

Comment: Oh I see, `memset` will wipe the garbage that is there... I wonder if that's needed.

Comment: @rofls Right after your malloc call, try doing `memset(result, 0, sizeof(struct node));`

Comment: @rofls Can you use your debugger to figure out at which line the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90838/discussion-between-cubia-and-rofls).